# How to make a copy of objects in constructor (instead of object reference)

Tags: java, list, unit-testing, constructor, pojo

I have a fairly simple POJO :

```
class POJO
{
   private final int id;   
   private final List<Name> names; //Name is another POJO

   POJO(final int id, final List<Name> names)
   {
     this.id = id;
     this.names = names;
   }
   
 public int getId() { return id; }
 public List<Name> getNames() { return names; }
}
```

The Name POJO looks like:

```
class Name
{
   private final String firstName;   
   private final String lastName;

   POJO(final String firstName, final List<Name> names)
   {
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
   }
   
 public int getFirstName() { return firstName; }
 public int getLastName() { return lastName; }
}
```

The class POJO stores a reference to the list of Name. To be safe, I want to make a copy of the list retrieved. For that, I tried modifying constructor to

```
this.names = new ArrayList<>();
this.names.addAll(names);
```

This is my test:

```
public class POJOTest
{
    private final int id = 1;
    private final List<Name> names = Mockito.mock(List.class);

    private final POJO target = new POJO(id, names);

    @Test
    public void testGetMethods()
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(id, target.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(names, target.getNames());
    }
}
```

My test case fails with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:582)
at POJO.<init>(POJO.java:38)
    at POJOTest.<init>(POJOTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

This is java:582:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        Object[] a = c.toArray();
        int numNew = a.length;
        ensureCapacityInternal(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
        size += numNew;
        return numNew != 0;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to make a copy in constructor?

Comment: Have you looked at ArrayList.java:582? What reference do you think is null? Please include your test case and the actual code for the POJO constructor in your question.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Now that you've looked at the code for addAll, do you understand what is the immediate cause of the NPE? That is, which dereference is causing the NPE? It is important that you learn to do this.

Comment: I am not sure. 'names' is null?

Comment: Line 582 is `int numNew = a.length`, so we suspect that the result of c.toArray() is null. Can you see why? What value does c have at this point? What happens when you call a method on a mock?

Comment: I just needed to change private final List<Name> names = Mockito.mock(List.class);  to private final List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>(); 
Mocking the list was causing it to be null. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this. @tgdavies

Comment: m glad you were able to figure out what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

from your question it is not clear where you want to store a copy of the names list.
I have created a copy in the POJO class so that every instance of POJO class will have its own copy of the names list.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class POJO {
    
     private final int id;   
     private final ArrayList<Name> names; //Name is another POJO
     private ArrayList<Name> namescopy;

       POJO(int id, ArrayList<Name> names)
       {
         this.id = id;
         this.names = names;
         
         namescopy = new ArrayList<Name>();
         
         Iterator<Name> it = names.iterator();
             
         while(it.hasNext()) {
             
             try { namescopy.add( (Name) it.next().clone()); } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
         }
         }
         
     public int getId() { return id; }
     public ArrayList<Name> getNames() { return names; }
     
     public ArrayList<Name> getNamesCopy() {
         
         return namescopy;
     }
}
```

```
package test;

public class Name implements Cloneable {
    private final String firstName ;   
       private final String lastName;

       Name( String firstName,  String lastName)
       {
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
       }
       
     public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
     public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
     public Object clone() throws
     CloneNotSupportedException 
     { 
     return super.clone(); 
     } 

}
```

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class POJOTest {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         
         Name a = new Name("Will", "Smith");
         Name b = new Name("Bruce", "Wayne");
         Name c = new Name("Will", "Turner");
    
        ArrayList<Name> namelist = new ArrayList<Name>();
        
        namelist.add(a);
        namelist.add(b);
        namelist.add(c);
         
        POJO p = new POJO(1, namelist);
         
        p.getNames().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.getFirstName()+" "+i.getLastName() +" "+ i));
        System.out.println();
        p.getNamesCopy().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.getFirstName()+" "+i.getLastName() +" "+ i));
     }
}
```